# Writing sets in set notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently struggling with set builder notation and translating sets described into it.
I have the following sets to rewrite:

```
(a) the set of all integer even numbers: S = {2x: x ∈ Z}
(b) the set of all odd integers: L = {2x + 1: x ∈ Z}
(c) the set of all powers of number 2 (with nonnegative integer exponent): M = {2 ^ x: x> 0, x ∈ N}
(d) the set of all integer divisors of the integer n: D = {x ∈ Z: n / x ∈ Z}
(e) the set of all integers that are the square of the odd integer: C = {2x - 1: x ∈ Z}
(f) the set of all integers that are the square root of an even number
(g) the set of all natural three-digit numbers
(h) the set of all natural numbers that have no two-digit divisor
(i) the set of all prime numbers (eg as a set of natural numbers that have exactly two
natural divisors; or in another way)
(j) the set of all natural numbers that have exactly 2021 natural divisors
```

I attempted, and think I got right the first few, but after that, I am completely lost. Could anyone help me with how to do the rest, or perhaps point me somewhere I could study up on this? I had little luck finding tutorials and things that I normally go for help first.

Comment: f) $\{n\in\mathbb N:n^2=2k\}$
g) $\{n\in\mathbb N:100\le n\le999\}$
h) $\{n\in\mathbb N:\forall d\in\mathbb N:10\le d\le99\implies d\not|n\}$
i) $\{p\in\mathbb N:\#\{d\in\mathbb N:d|p\}=2\}$
j) $\{p\in\mathbb N:\#\{d\in\mathbb N:d|p\}=2021\}$

Comment: Exercises like this can give a skewed notion of what mathematical notation is allowed, useful, and preferred. If I had to denote the set from (j), for example, I would likely just write $\{n \in \Bbb{N} : n \text{ has exactly } 2021 \text{ natural divisors}\}$, as this is more human-readable and not that much more onerous than writing anything with symbols.